# how to handle upload a file in rest assured API testing?

Tags: rest-assured

how to handle upload a file in rest assured API testing ?

like  u have to use post(/url) and then upload a file at specific paramater.?

Comment: can convert the file to base64 encoding and send as a string

Answer (score 5):

Hope this will help, works fine for me

```
given().
        multiPart(KEY, new File(testfile)).
            formParam(KEY, testfile).
                contentType("multipart/form-data").
    expect().
        body("user.name", equalTo(someuserdata)).
            when().
                post(yourapihere);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send Multipart data . For Rest assured, its documented here: http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#Multi-part_form_data